# AWS-cognito -- not getting tokens after sign-in to application

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am working in AWS-cognito with angular application, in that I have not received tokens after redirecting to my dashboard.

Comment: Maybe show the code you're using so we can help you.

Comment: Hi Nagalakshmi, thanks for posting the question. Please share the relevant code here and make sure you replace all credentials and user pool id/links that are private to our project. Thanks

Comment: onLoginClick(){
  
  const URL="https://finity-web.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/signup?response_type=code&client_id=2770pio4plmettraat9ctdmkng&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200"; 
  window.open(URL);
  console.log(URL);
}

Comment: in main.ts file

Comment: import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

Comment: const oauth = {
  domain: 'finity-web.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
  scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
  redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:4200'
  redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:4200'
  responseType: 'code',
  options: {
    AdvancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: false
  },
  // urlOpener: urlOpener
}

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onLoginClick()">Login</button>

Comment: onLoginClick(){

  const URL="https://finity-web.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/signup?response_type=code&client_id=2770pio4plmettraat9ctdmkng&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200"; 
  window.open(URL);
  console.log(URL);
}

Comment: please go through above code i cannot post the code at a time